# ConTeXt: number formulas side by side

Tags: equations, numbering, context

In ConTeXt we can position formulas side by side by using `\startformulas…\stopformulas`.

```
\starttext
\placeformula
\startformulas
  \startformula
    \startalign[number=auto]
      \NC a \NC= b \NR
      \NC a \NC= b \NR
    \stopalign
  \stopformula
  \startformula
    \startalign[number=auto]
      \NC a \NC= b \NR
      \NC a \NC= b \NR
    \stopalign
  \stopformula
\stopformulas
\stoptext
```

According to [this MyWay from 2006](http://dl.contextgarden.net/myway/mathalign.pdf) (page 6) numbering formulas side-by-side should work as above. But I get the following output:

[image: formula numbering]

How to place equations side-by-side and have the numbering not clash into the next one?

Comment: I changed your MWE a little to support both the new (`[number=auto]`) and the old (`\NR[+]`) numbering syntax: http://dpaste.com/3BP4B0G (Expires in 7 days).  Then I ran it through some old TeX Live versions:
[2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzmrL.png),
[2016](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAob6.png),
[2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QetYi.png),
[2018](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7m7S3.png),
[2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX06A.png).
Looks like in 2017 it broke.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks for testing. I have found a workaround. But I'm not sure whether the above example should basically work or is unsupported by now.

Comment: @TeXnician: This is a bug. Please report it to the context mailing list.

Comment: @Fólkvangr What is the original "indentation"? White space is arbitrary in this case. And why should `\startalign` act like an option?

Comment: @Fólkvangr Well, I have read about the feature in the MyWay. But the sample code has been written by me. And as my editor does insert line breaks this way, I simply kept them while copy and pasting. Indentation is not relevant to the broken functionality here (I did not test, so feel free to prove me wrong). The issue here simply is the numbering clashing into the next formula. I have posted this [on the mailing list](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2019/096453.html) as told by Aditya and they did not mention that the formatting would be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve this seems to be the `columns` environment. Although the markup is not that expressive, it prevents the numbers clashing into the next formula.

```
\starttext
\startcolumns
  \placeformula
  \startformula
    \startalign[number=auto]
      \NC a \NC= b \NR
      \NC a \NC= b \NR
    \stopalign
  \stopformula
  \placeformula
  \startformula
    \startalign[number=auto]
      \NC a \NC= b \NR
      \NC a \NC= b \NR
    \stopalign
  \stopformula
\stopcolumns
\stoptext
```